# Biblatex: pagebackref reference in the (flush) right margin

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

Since I am not really satisfied with how pages where a bibliographic reference is called in the text are reflected in the bibliography, I tried to modify the `pageref` macro in Biblatex as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{saad00,
  title = {Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems},
  year = {2000},
  author = {Y. Saad}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% pagereference in the right margin
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
   \iflistundef{pageref}
     {}
     {\printtext{\hfill\rlap{\hskip15pt\colorbox{blue!5}{\scriptsize\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}}}

\begin{document}
text \cite{saad00}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem, I think, is in the `\hfill` that pushes to the right a punctuation related to a previous block, the `year` entry in the given example. I know how to get rid of this problem by hooking the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}` in the `.bbx` file but I would be happy if there is a simpler solution directly in the `pageref` macro.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try redefining the bibmacro `pageref` in this way:

```
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
   \iflistundef{pageref}
     {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}
     {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addspace}%
      \printtext{\addperiod\hfill\rlap{\hskip15pt\colorbox{blue!5}{\scriptsize\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}}}
```

If `pageref` is undefined, the meaning of `\finentrypunct` is left unchanged, while when it is defined, we redefine `\finentrypunct` to be `\addspace` and we add `\addperiod` before `\hfill`. In this way it works fine even when using `\nocite`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{saad00,
  title = {Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems},
  year = {2000},
  author = {Y. Saad}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% pagereference in the right margin
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
   \iflistundef{pageref}
     {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}
     {\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addspace}%
      \printtext{\addperiod\hfill\rlap{\hskip15pt\colorbox{blue!5}{\scriptsize\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}}}

\begin{document}
text \cite{saad00}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]